# Criar um "carregando..." real?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Andei pesquisando uns efeitos legais para um status de "Carregando..."
Porém percebi que em todos os sites, eles usam *timeout* para que a animação entre e saia da página, sendo então, só uma cobertura bonita de um bolo qualquer.Então eu parei para pensar, teria como fazer esse *timeout* baseado no tempo de *response* ? Vi no Google Chrome que ao abrir as Ferramentas de desenvolvedor, e ir na aba *network* aparece o tempo total que essa troca de dados levou para ser retornada ao usuário que está no site.

Então peço que imaginem qualquer troca de dados com jQuery, Ajax ou qualquer outro e que enquanto essa troca de dados é feita, isto entra em vigor:

```
$('#elementoqualquer').prepend('<img src="/img/ajax-loader.gif" align="absmiddle">');
```

Isto é possível? Qual o nome desse processo?

Comment: Queres que sempre que seja buscado conteúdo exterior essa imagem seja mostrada? tens ajax no site? seria mais fácil limitar isso ao ajax, não estou a ver como saber se o browser está a receber dados...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Na verdade funciona assim: A requisição ajax tem *[eventos](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#callback-functions)*, um deles é o de conclusão, `success` no caso do jQuery. Então o processo fica simples. Você *mostra* a imagem quando abrir a requisição, e *esconde*  quando ela terminar, no evento success. Não precisa calcular tempo nenhum. Exemplo em jQuery:

```
function IniciarRequisicao() {
    // Mostra imagem na chamada da requisição
    $(".img-carregando").show();

    $.ajax({
        url: "endpoint.php",
        success: function() {
            // Fim da requição
            $(".img-carregando").hide();
        }
    });
}

IniciarRequisicao();
```

Pra ser sincero o correto é usar no evento `complete`, pois se usada apenas no `success` e se houver um erro na requisição, a imagem não é oculta.

Answer (score 4):

Já criei isso da seguinte maneira. No cabeçalho da página, coloco todos os arquivos de CSS e o jQuery e no rodapé da página antes do fechamento da tag `body` adiciono o restante dos scripts e um script incorporado, como no exemplo:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Exemplo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/estilos.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/estilos1.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/estilos2.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/estilos3.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="loading"><img src="./img/loading.gif" alt="Carregando..."></div>
    <div id="conteudo">
        <!-- Restante do conteúdo da página -->
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $('#loading').hide('fade');
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/script1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/script2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/script3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/script4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/script5.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

O exemplo demonstrado funciona da seguinte maneira:

1. É carregado os arquivos referênte ao CSS e o jQuery
2. Quando o navegador começa a renderizar a página, o elemento `div#loading` é o primeiro a ser criado.

<sub>Ele deve conter uma classe CSS que fique sobre o restante da página, como um `position:fixed; z-index: 10000;` ou outro a seu gosto. Enquanto a página está sendo montada ele está sendo exibido.</sub>

3. Quando o browser termina de renderizar a página, o evento `onload` entra em ação e o método `jQuery(document).ready(...)` é executado, e dentro desse método ocultamos o `div#loading`

Isso seria o mais próximo à um "carregando real". Outra forma seria carregar apenas apenas o javascript responsável por esse "carregando" e um outro para buscar o restante da página via AJAX como na resposta do @Marcio, essa seria um pouco mais próximo ao "carregando real", porém um pouco mais trabalhoso, já que teria que se preocupar bastante com o que você precisa buscar.

Answer (score 2):

Pode se usar o `jQuery.ajaxSetup`, exemplo:

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
    complete: function(){
       //fechar o feedback ao usuário
    },
    beforeSend: function(){
        //mostrar o feedback ao usuário
    }
});
```

Documentação: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/

:)